# Set product units in Magento

Tags: magento

i have products that are sold per KG, per Box or per part. I don't want the customer to choose which unit he wants, just show it. 
How can i set the product unit in magento? is there a built in functionality, extension,..?

i followed this 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-the-unit-price

but i can't find the unit price section

Comment: Magento's only standard unit of measure is each. You don't have the ability to have different units of measure. Basically maintain stock as 1 of the UOM for that product and note it in the product name, etc. There are modules available to make that limitation go away.

Comment: The link is for Magento Go which is an animal of a different color.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is covered by this extension:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/baseprice-modul-basic-grundpreis-modul-pangv.html

It enables you to set a unit and display price based on this unit.